# Removing all rows where a column entry is only listed once, but display all other columns too (subquery)

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to clean my data by removing all of a certain column that is only listed once or twice. It currently looks like this:

| Fruit | Year | Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apples | 2018 | 20000 |
| oranges | 2018 | 600 |
| apples/oranges | 2018 | 3000 |
| oranges | 2017 | 6000 |
| apples | 2016 | 2000 |
| oranges | 2016 | 2000 |
| apples | 2017 | 50000 |
| potato | 2017 | 9000 |
| apples/oranges | 2016 | 5000 |

I would like it to look like this:

| Fruit | Year | Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apples | 2018 | 20000 |
| oranges | 2018 | 600 |
| apples | 2017 | 50000 |
| oranges | 2017 | 6000 |
| apples | 2016 | 2000 |
| oranges | 2016 | 2000 |

There are a lot more Fruit single entries than this in the table in reality so I can not just exclude using a long `where` statement.

**Attempted solution**

I've tried to simplify the data by using a subquery that counts the number of times a "Fruit" entry appears , then only displays rows where this is two or more. It works as a standalone query but not in the larger query which also includes the other columns.

```
SELECT "Fruit"
    ,count("Fruit") as cnt
    ,"Year"
    ,"Units"
FROM example_table
WHERE(SELECT count("Fruit") as cnt
    FROM example_table
    HAVING cnt > 2)
GROUP BY "Fruit"
    ,"Year"
    ,"Units"
```

This is the error message I get:

`Invalid data type [NUMBER(18,0)] for predicate [(SELECT COUNT(EXAMPLE_TABLE."Fruit") AS "CNT" FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE AS EXAMPLE_TABLE HAVING CNT > 2)]`

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: When pinned down the problems will be faqs. (Clearly.) Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]. Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is getting the fruit names that have more than 2 then you can select them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM example_table 
WHERE Fruit in (
SELECT Fruit 
FROM example_table
group by Fruit
having count(Fruit) > 2)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

FUNCTIONS USED;

[QUALIFY()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)

[image]

```
WITH CTE AS  
(SELECT 'apples'    FRUITS, 2018 YEAR,  20000 UNITS
UNION ALL SELECT 'oranges', 2018 YEAR,  600 UNITS
UNION ALL SELECT 'oranges', 2017 YEAR,  6000 UNITS
UNION ALL SELECT 'apples',  2016 YEAR,  2000 UNITS
UNION ALL SELECT 'oranges', 2016 YEAR,  2000 UNITS
UNION ALL SELECT 'apples',  2017 YEAR,  50000 UNITS
UNION ALL SELECT 'potato',  2017 YEAR,  9000 UNITS
UNION ALL SELECT 'apples/oranges' , 2016,   5000
UNION ALL SELECT 'apples/oranges',  2018,   3000 )

SELECT * FROM CTE 
    QUALIFY COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR)OVER(PARTITION BY FRUITS)>2;
```